# Internet Explorer Website show blank page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

i have a strange problem with a site but only with Internet Explorer!

When i open the website ie load only the background-color but if i press F12 on my keyboard witch open developer tool and then i refresh the page the website show up normally without any problem ... any suggestion?

Comment: Sounds like you got some "console.log"'s in your javascript. IE can't interpret these when the developer console isn't open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess its because you are using console.log in your code

console.log is available after you open Developer Tools in IE. Use a try catch;

```
try{
    console.log('log')
}
catch(err){
}
```

Comment: Thank you! after removing all console.log() lines from the webpage all works without any error!!!